# How to send JSON with dictionary and array in iOS(Objective c )?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-2.0

I am trying to send a JSON to websocket. the required format is coming up with commas whereas when i add item to dictionary then its creating a semi-colon.

**Required Format :**

```
{"key":"driver_location_updates","driverID":40,"coordinates":[25.22632,55.2844576]}
```

**Format I created :**

```
"driver_location_updates" =    
   {
       coordinates = ( "24.96046731716484","67.05977029173361"); 
       driverID = 16;
       key = "driver_location_updates"; 
   };
}
```

Comment: LOLX both are same

Comment: farq tou hai ... :(

Comment: Don't go for logs, both are same if you are worried about that semi-colon.

Comment: 1.key is not  with inverted commas . 2. There is Semi-colon after end of every value  3. Round Bracket in coordinates

Comment: @warzone_fz Chck my ans, if still have doubt then ask.

Answer (score 1):

**As you said in comments**

1. key is not with inverted commas.
2. There is Semi-colon after end of every value
3. Round Bracket in coordinates

**Explanation :**

1. Because your key is single worded so it is assumable that it is string (as there is chars not integer). Try by keeping key as two words like `key mine` or `key_2`

> Output **=>** [image]

2. Because after every key in dictionary there is semi-colon. (x-code syntax for dictionanary).
3. Because array in console is represented in **`(...)`** where as dictionary will be represented in **`{...}`**.

Now, more over if you observe there is `=` in Dictionary but in json there is `:`. It is just because array dictionary notation is different from json.

By considering the above points, it makes you clear that both are same.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `JSONSerialization` to convert dictionary to json I guess.

```
let dictionary: [String: Any] = ["key":"driver_location_updates", "driverID": 40, "coordinates": [25.22632,55.2844576]]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)
print(jsonString)
```

I hope you know how to convert the answer to `Objective C`

Answer (score 0):

From the format I guess you have used `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"]` or got the "JSON" from a call to `-[NSDictionary description]`.

This does not create JSON, but a general, human readable notation of the data structure. It kind of looks like JSON and I had the exact same issue many years back :)

Use `NSJSONSerialization` to get real JSON:

```
NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 &error];
```

or directly write to a stream

```
[NSJSONSerialization writeJSONObject:dictionary toStream:writeStream options:0 error:&error]
```